# Composer / SVN Repository sync

Tags: php, svn, composer-php, packagist

I've problem in configuring either satis or composer. What I've managed to do so far:

1: I've created a SVN repository called "common". There are several tags (1.0, 1.1) - each tag has its own composer.json file, eg:

```
{
    "name": "acme/common",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

SVN URL: http://svn.local.acme.com/svn/common

2: I've created composer repository from satis.json:

```
{
    "name": "Acme",
    "homepage": "http://dev.local.acme.com/satis/web",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://svn.local.acme.com/svn/common" }
    ],
    "require-all": true
}
```

It did pull all tags into web/packages.json:

```
{
    "packages": {
        "acme/common": {
            "1.0": {
                "name": "acme/common",
                "version": "1.0",
                "version_normalized": "1.0.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "http://svn.local.acme.com/svn/common",
                    "reference": "/tags/1.0/@2"
                },
                "type": "library"
            },
            "1.1": {
                "name": "acme/common",
                "version": "1.1",
                "version_normalized": "1.1.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "http://svn.local.acme.com/svn/common",
                    "reference": "/tags/1.1/@5"
                },
                "type": "library"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Satis URL: http://dev.local.acme.com/satis/web

3: In my project I want to require "acme/common" in my composer.json (lets say 1.0):

```
{
    "require": {
        "acme/common": "1.0"
    },

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://dev.local.acme.com/satis/web"
        }
    ]
}
```

It successfully pulls 1.0 tag, however if I change the require to "1.1" and run `composer.phar update` I get an error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                        
  Package could not be downloaded, svn: E195012: Path '.' does not share common version control ancestry with the requested switch location.  Use --ignore-ancestry to disable this check.  
  svn: E195012: 'http://svn.local.acme.com/svn/common/tags/1.3' shares no common ancestry with '/home/user/acid.dev.local.acme.com/composer/vendor/acme/common'
```

I think the problem here is that initially (composer install) checkouts the tag instead of import import. This error designates that vendor dir is SVN versioned (it has .svn folder) - I don't think it should be.